# Can Azure-Search be used on a local folder? On a remote website?

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

There is a website titled "discover the networks" that shows the relationships between various personalities and organizations on the left of the political spectrum.   I would like to try Azure Search, perhaps with cognitive services, on this site, and see if any interesting relationships are found. 
  This could be used in any diagram of relationships, and for any type of politics too - for instance, did a friend of Paul Manafort have a link to Russian intelligence.

There are two problems with my idea:

1. The site (Discover The Networks) requires subscription, and probably I would not have access to the data
2. I don't what formats that 'Azure Search' expects.   Does it expect a folder on my PC full of text files (or PDFs or Word files)  and images?  Can you use it on online websites belonging to other people?

As far as objection #1, I can probably get other data of that nature just to test the program out.   But I could use an answer on #2.

Thanks.
8 hours 18 minutes ago

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure Search service can be used to query over data that was previously “indexed” to it.

You can use Azure Search’s REST API (or SDK) to index data to your Azure Search service, or alternatively you can define an “indexer” that would read data from a data source and index it.

Currently indexers only support the following data sources:

- Azure SQL
- Azure Cosmos DB
- Azure Blob Storage
- Azure Table Storage

I’m afraid there is no “web crawler” indexer :)
 

You can find more info about indexers here - [Indexer in Azure Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-indexer-overview)